# Google places not returning specific types

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I tried to use the following code to get only the `park` and `establishment` in the country `us` for my google places Auto-complete.

```
function initialize() {

 var options = {
  types: ['(park)', '(establishment)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
 };

 var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}
```

But it is not returning any results in the search field. When I tried

```
var options = {
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
};
```

it did work.

How can I get only the parks in US ?

Comment: I've mentioned the desired behavior, my problem, and the code which I used. What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: You didn't provide a **Complete** example.  The code posted will not reproduce the problem.  Please provide a fiddle or a SO code snippet that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @geocodezip: I think he already provided the shortest possible code for the problem mentioned here. This would be enough to analyze the case. Why are you changing your opinions every time regarding this problem?

Comment: @geocodezip, yes, I guess this code is causing the problem. And this is not an example, but exact portion of code from my application that I'm working on.

Comment: You can instantiate your Autocomplete so results are restricted within a country with the componentRestriction option. You can also restrict results to a certain type of places with the types option, but the only choices are 'geocode', 'establishment', '(regions)', '(cities)'. Schools and universities are of 'establishment' type, so you will get them if you use this, but they'll be retrieved along with any business establishment.

Comment: Did you try park without establishment? They seem like they might be mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Scott Yes I tried. But it is not working.

Comment: I tried to duplicate your problem using http and I can't replicate. Maybe it's related to your platform. Did you try specifying lat and long?  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?key=<mykey>&location=33.9459,-84.3598&rankby=distance&sensor=true&type=park&country=us

Comment: lat and long for the map or for the google places?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Google's official documentation on Place Autocomplete only a single "type" parameter is allowed. The only exception is to mix the "establishment" & "geocode" type. I think you are putting in the "type" parameter for the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types).

Apart from that there is no "park" type mentioned in that document. For more details please see this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#place_types).